# Meaning of two arrows below the limit sign

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following expression whose precise meaning I am trying to decipher:
[image]

where the first term is a function of both $n$ and $t$, where as the second is only of $t$. I would like to know precisely what the limit with the two arrows bellow means.

Could someone give me a precise analysis definition of this?

**EDIT:** Here is the statement and proof

[image]

[image]

Comment: If "the first term is a function of both n and t, it should be written $y_n(t)$, not just $y_n.$ Alternatively, you should put parenthesis around $y_n-y.$

Comment: Another problem is that $h$ appears (twice) below the $\lim$ sign, but nowhere in your function.

Comment: Apologies but this is not my work. I took the screenshot from a collection of notes. I am trying to understand what the author meant.

Comment: If so, could you please give some more context, so that we can "repair" (and explain) this formula?

Comment: Of course. The context is Numerical Analysis and this is part of a theorem for the convergence of the Euler Method.

Comment: By "more context" we mean please [edit] the question to show us enough of the surrounding text.

Comment: I have added the whole statement and the proof. Some of the notation I bealive is standard but if that is also required, I can be found at https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IB_L/numerical_analysis.pdf from page 27 onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+hf(t_n,y_n)\quad\text{and}\quad t_n=nh,$$
$y_n$ depends on $n$ but also (implicitely) on $h$ (but not on any $t$).

The two conditions $h\to0,nh\to t$ are redundant.

$nh\to t$ (as $n\to\infty$) is sufficient.

The $\epsilon-\delta$ translation of this limit is:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\Bbb N,\exists\delta>0\quad\forall n\ge N,\forall h\in\left[\frac{t-\delta}n,\frac{t+\delta}n\right]\quad|y_n-y(t)|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Hi. So one lets $nh$ be a constant at takes the limit as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: No, $nh$ is not constant. $n$ tends to $\infty$ and $hn\to t$ (so $h\sim\frac tn\to0$). If you prefer: let $y_n=Y(n,h)$ one takes $\lim_{n\to\infty,k\to t}(Y(n,k/n)-y(t)).$

Comment: At least, that is what is claimed in the (i) statement of the theorem. But it seems the author is cheating in the proof and only does what you write, i.e. he takes $t=t_n=nh.$

Comment: I apologise but I do not follow. Could you give the epsilon-delta version of the statement instead?